# PipelineDB arrival_timestamp field does not appear

Tags: pipelinedb

I'm using PipelineDB together with pgAdmin, and when I go to create a foreign table the "arrival_timestamp" field does not appear. Furthermore, when I create a continuous view, an error is generated: `unidentified sw parameter`.

This is the [guide](http://docs.pipelinedb.com/installation.html) I followed to install PipelineDB. I do the paragraph commands "apt" and "Creating the PipelineDB Extension".

These are the queries I wrote:

[image]

Comment: Please modify your question and include your queries rather than having a link to a picture of them.

Comment: @Zatchy what versions of PipelineDB/PostgreSQL are you running, and on which OS?